# Qt property outside of base class

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Im using a QML frontend for my C++ App which worked fine so far. However, I planned to tidy up my code and split functions into smaller classes

At first, my Property decleration looked like this:

```
class mainBoard : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(double baroAltitude MEMBER baroAltitude NOTIFY pressureChanged)

public:
explicit mainBoard(QObject *parent = 0);
void start();

private:
   double baroAltitude = 0;
signals:
   void pressureChanged();
};
```

Now, I do have this external class, with my getter method.

```
#include "pressuresensor.h"

class mainBoard : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(double baroAltitude READ pressureSensors.getBaroAltitude NOTIFY pressureSensors.pressureChanged)

public:
explicit mainBoard(QObject *parent = 0);
void start();

private:
   pressureSensor pressureSensors;
};
```

But now, all I get is:

```
mainboard.h:25: Parse error at "pressureSensors"
error: [moc_mainboard.cpp] Error 1
```

Is there a better, or correct (because its working :D ) way for it?

thanks!

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html *"A NOTIFY signal is optional. If defined, it should specify one existing signal **in that class**..."* Emphasis mine. So, add a signal to `mainBoard`, connect it to `pressureSensors` signal in the constructor. Or, use `WRITE` instead of `NOTIFY` and emit the appropriate signal yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`Q_PROPERTY` does not support getters/setters methods which are not part of the class in question.
If you really want to keep the `pressureSensor` class you have to provide getters/setters in the `mainBoard` class and forward the calls.

```
class mainBoard : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(double baroAltitude READ getBaroAltitude)

public:
double getBaroAltitude() const {
    return pressureSensors.getBaroAlitude();
}

private:
   pressureSensor pressureSensors;
};
```